# Control MATLAB IDE window size from within MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is there any way to resize the MATLAB IDE using MATLAB code?  I want to be able to maximize the window or have it take up half the screen from a script.  This is on a Windows machine.

I can probably call out to an external program like AutoHotkey to do it, but am wondering if there is a native way.

Comment: The first half of the oldest answer in the duplicate question should do what you want.

Comment: I want to resize the actual MATLAB IDE window (editor, command window, workspace window, etc), not a user generated GUI.  How do I do that?  set(0,'Position', [1 1 1000 1000]) does not work.

Comment: Ah shoot I'm sorry.  I misread your question.  A visit to `java.awt.Robot` may be useful.  Let me have a look and I'll write an answer.

Comment: I can't mark another duplicate, but try Luis Mendo's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31281037/3250829 .  You're using Windows so this should work.  It exploits using the `java.awt.Robot` class and programatically maximizes the window in focus.

Comment: Robot seems pretty cool.  Might be useful.  I'm thinking of doing something along the lines of this http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/setting-the-matlab-desktop-layout-programmatically

Comment: Ah, that could work!  Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a handle to the desktop:

```
desktop = com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance;
desktop.getMainFrame.setSize(1200, 1000)
desktop.getMainFrame.setLocation(0, 0)
```