# How to save a Matlab plot maximized?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have this code:

```
fig = figure('visible','on');
plot(0:0.1:2*pi,sin(0:0.1:2*pi))
grid on
grid minor
set(gca,'FontSize',20,'xtick',0:0.5:2*pi)
saveas(fig,'plot','png')
```

When the plot is saved, it is not maximized and hence the tick numbers cram into each other.
I used the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286458/automatically-maximize-figure-in-matlab), but it did not work:

```
fig = figure('visible','on');
plot(0:0.1:2*pi,sin(0:0.1:2*pi))
grid on
grid minor
set(gca,'FontSize',20,'xtick',0:0.5:2*pi)
set(gcf,'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])
saveas(fig,'plot','png')
```

How can I save the figure fully maximized?

The good saved plot when I manually saved it:
[image]

The bad one which is saved programmatically:
[image]

Comment: My recomendation is always: use `export_fig` from the file exchange

Comment: you may take a look to my recently added answer [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286458/automatically-maximize-figure-in-matlab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of solutions given in the quoted post. The following solution works for me:

```
fig = figure('visible','on');
plot(0:0.1:2*pi,sin(0:0.1:2*pi))
grid on
grid minor
set(gca,'FontSize',20,'xtick',0:0.5:2*pi)
pause(0.1)
frame_h = get(handle(gcf),'JavaFrame');
set(frame_h,'Maximized',1);
pause(0.1)
set(fig, 'PaperPositionMode', 'auto');
saveas(fig,'plot','png')
```

Best regards

Comment: It works. However, it gives this warning->
`Warning: figure JavaFrame property will be obsoleted in a future release`